# what is the purpose of collision

Tags: collision

Hello   I just want to know what is a collision exactly? the word means clash or two objects got hit together ( this is the meaninng I got in google translate when translated it to my language).
What is the need of it?  and should I do it for all objects that I want to export from blender to unreel engine 5? if not, when to use it?

Comment: It is used to create obstacles for the Cloth or Soft Body objects

Comment: so i dont need to put it on every object in the scene

Comment: only on the ones that are supposed to interact with cloth or soft bodies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Physics, *Collision* is used to create obstacles for the *Cloth* or *Soft Body* objects, only give it to the objects that are supposed to interact with cloth or soft bodies

Comment: not sure why it has been downvoted  ^^  don't hesitate to explain

Comment: what is the downvoted?

Comment: someone downvoted my answer (down arrow), I'm not sure why, if my answer is wrong I prefer to know why

Comment: Iam not sure man, your answer helped me understanding the idea